Express middleware called from the wrong route when routes are partial matches
I am using express.js 4.21.0.
If I declare my app like so:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const r1 = express.Router();

r1.use((req, res)=> {
    console.log('r1 middleware');
});

r1.get('/a', function (req, res) {
    return res.send('x');
});

const r2 = express.Router();

r2.get('/b', function (req, res) {
    return res.send('y');
});

app.use('/wherever', r1);
app.use('/wherever/else', r2);
app.use('/elsewhere', r2);

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server ready');
});


Then run my app using node index.js and make a request to http://localhost:8080/api/wherever/else/b I can see r1 middleware printed in the console.
However, if I make the same request to http://localhost:8080/api/elsewhere/b then the r1 middleware is NOT printed.
How can I make it so my r2 router is available at http://localhost:8080/api/wherever/else/b but DOES NOT cause invocation of r1 middleware?

Let's register specific routers first, and make sure that priority routes don't cover other routers:
app.use('/wherever/else', r2); // go first
app.use('/wherever', r1); // match any thing like `/wherever/*` except `/wherever/else`
app.use('/elsewhere', r2);

